# Rails Nested Forms Not Updating Nested Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-forms, update-attributes

I am having trouble trying to update nested models in my form. I don't get any errors and but the attributes don't get updated.

I have the following model:

```
class Trip < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :segments
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :segments, allow_destroy: true
end

class Segment < ActiveRecord::Base  
  belongs_to :start_location, class_name: 'Location'
  belongs_to :end_location, class_name: 'Location'
  belongs_to :trip

  validates_presence_of :date, :start_location, :end_location  
end

class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :segments
end
```

And have this code in the _form.html.erb:

```
<%= form_for @trip do |f| %>
...
  <%= f.fields_for :segments do |builder| %>
    <%= render 'segment_fields', f: builder %>
  <% end %>
...
<% end %>
```

And this in the partial _segment_fields.html.erb:

```
<%= f.collection_select :start_location_id, Location.order(:name), :id, :name %> -
<%= f.collection_select :end_location_id, Location.order(:name), :id, :name %> <br>
<%= f.date_field :date %>
```

In my controller I also permited the assigment of :segments_attributes

```
def trip_params
  params.require(:trip).permit(:name, :start_date, :end_date, :segments_attributes)
end
```

Does anybody know what I am lacking or doing wrong?

Comment: Can you post the server log generated while submitting the form? And also your `trip_params` should be `params.require(:trip).permit(:name, :start_date, :end_date, segments_attributes: [:id,:start_location_id,:end_location_id,:date])`

Comment: It started working perfect with that change! Anyway the server log is:  Parameters: {..., "trip"=>{"name"=>"Sudeste2", "start_date"=>"2014-07-01", "end_date"=>"2014-07-31", "segments_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"start_location_id"=>"1", "end_location_id"=>"8", "date"=>"2014-06-30", "id"=>"2"}}}, "commit"=>"Update Trip", "id"=>"1"}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are *creating a new record you don't need its **id** to be permitted* as it's not been created but ***when you want to update your record you need to pass id to the permitted attributes***, else it will work with create but not when you want to update your record, so you need to do:

```
def trip_params
  params.require(:trip).permit(:id, :name, :start_date, :end_date,  segments_attributes: [:id,:start_location_id,:end_location_id, :date])
end
```

Comment: I have a question about setting the `:id` in strong parameters. Why? I'm very confused as to how that id is at all associating itself because it doesn't really match the DB id. Also, I do notice that it says `Unpermitted parameter: id`. So I definitely believe you. But this isn't documented very well.

Comment: @Andy The `id` attribute in `segments_attributes` is not the `Trip`'s `id` but the `Segment`'s `id`. Remember: they are two different records in the database here. A `Trip` and a `Segment`. They have one `id` each.